# URL Encoding (Time Zone) (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I'm trying to post a url with a time_zone but I'm facing the following problem

In my method I have:

```
base_url = "..."
time_zone = "Alaska" # works
#time_zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" # doesn't work
#time_zone = "Pacific%20Time%20(US%20%26%20Canada)" # doesn't work either 
#time_zone = "Pacific Time" # doesn't work
@url = "#{base_url}?time_zone=#{time_zone}"
@url = URI.encode(@url)
... # connect here
```

The available selection for time_zones are here http://developer.pagerduty.com/documentation/rest/types#timezone

If I supply for example "Alaska" I get data but I need "Pacific Time (US & Canada)" and it's not working.

I tried using http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ to encode my URL but it doesn't work either.

Anything more I'm not paying attention to?

EDIT: "Pacific Time" doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just be:

```
time_zone = "Pacific%20Time"
```

**Edit:**

> The problem was using
>
> ```
> URI.encode(url)
> ```

What you want is URI.encode_www_form:

```
require 'uri'

url = "http://www.example.com/time_zone=Pacific Time (US & Canada)&count=10"
p URI.encode url

query_string = URI.encode_www_form(
  [
    ["time_zone", "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"],
    ["count", 10]
  ]
)
p query_string

--output:--
"http://www.example.com/time_zone=Pacific%20Time%20(US%20&%20Canada)"
"time_zone=Pacific+Time+%28US+%26+Canada%29&count=10"
```

The ampersand in the "US & Canada" part obviously needs to be escaped, but URI.encode fails to do that.  I'm really surprised anyone would pick a time zone name with an ampersand in the middle of it.  Are you sure "Pacific Time" won't work by itself?  For instance,

```
"http://www.example.com/time_zone=Pacific%20Time"
```

or

```
"http://www.example.com/time_zone=Pacific+Time"
```

Note that URI.encode_www_form implements the www.w3.org specs:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data

which warns:

> This form data set encoding is in many ways an aberrant monstrosity,
>   the result of many years of implementation accidents and compromises
>   leading to a set of requirements necessary for interoperability, but
>   in no way representing good design practices. In particular, readers
>   are cautioned to pay close attention to the twisted details involving
>   repeated (and in some cases nested) conversions between character
>   encodings and byte sequences.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was using

```
"URI.encode(url)"
```

This worked:

```
base_url = "..."
time_zone = "Pacific%20Time%20(US%20%26%20Canada)" 
@url = "#{base_url}?time_zone=#{time_zone}"
# @url = URI.encode(@url) # this made it not work!
 ... # connect here
```

Comment: I added some comments to my answer, which might prove helpful.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I "know" that the `(US & Canada)` part is just a comment in that list of time zones.  Otherwise, someone not familiar with time zones in the US would have no idea what country Pacific Time referred to.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought at first but it's not http://developer.pagerduty.com/documentation/rest/types#timezone